# haskell function type simplifyed f :: ((b -> a ) -> a -> c ) -> (b -> a ) -> b -> c

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, logic, declarative

Just looking for an explanation of the type of this function, please

In functional programming this refers to the study of the type of returned values.

`f x y z = x y (y z)`

Prelude is the haskell interpreter which solves it as:

`f :: ((b  -> a) -> a  -> c) -> (b  -> a) -> b  -> c`

But I'm not able getting that result with any known method ¬¬

Best regards.

Comment: Is this a homework question? Can you show us what you’ve tried so far?

Comment: by "Prelude" you probably mean `Prelude> `?

Comment: NB `f :: ((b -> a) -> a -> c) -> (b -> a) -> b -> c` == `f :: ((b -> a) -> (a -> c)) -> (b -> a) -> (b -> c)`. thus `f ba_ac ba = ba >>> (ba & ba_ac) :: {ba >>> ac} :: bc`, as shown in the answer by @leftaroundabout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ugh, those “manually typecheck this expression” exercises are so silly. I don't know why lecturers keep putting them in assignments.

In practice, what's actually much more relevant is to go the other way around: *given a type, find an implementation*. So let me answer the question from that angle: you already know

```
f :: ((b -> a) -> a -> c) -> (b -> a) -> b -> c
--   └──────────────────┘    └──────┘   └─┘
```

...so you have three arguments to accept, reasonable enough to call them `x`, `y` and `z`

```
f x y z = _
```

You're in the end looking for a `c`, and the only `c` you have available is in the final result of `x`

```
    x :: (b -> a) -> a -> c
    --   └──────┘   └─┘
```

...which requires two arguments

```
f x y z = x _ _
```

...of types `b -> a` and `a`. Let's check what we have available

```
    y :: b -> a
    z :: b
```

Great, we can directly use `y` as the first argument

```
f x y z = x y _
```

For the second argument we need an `a`. Well, `z` is a `b`, that doesn't work, but `y` yields an `a` when given a `b`, so we can pass `y z` and thus end up with

```
f x y z = x y (y z)
```

or as we prefer to write it in Haskell, `f x y = x y . y`.

Now for the other way around: let's start with the η-reduced form

```
f x y = x y . y
```

This is a pipeline, so let's start giving the passing-through argument a name `p`

```
        x y . y :: p -> _
```

That argument is passed first to `y`, so we have

```
        y :: p -> _
```

from which it follows, since `y` is also the first argument to `x`

```
        x :: (p -> _) -> _
```

Furthermore, `x` then accepts (in the pipeline) whatever comes out of `y`

```
        y :: p -> r
        x :: (p -> r) -> r -> _
```

Let's call the final result `q`

```
        y :: p -> r
        x :: (p -> r) -> r -> q
```

And write up the whole function as given:

```
(\x y -> x y . y) :: ((p -> r) -> r -> q) -> (p -> r) -> p -> q
--                   └─────────x────────┘    └──y───┘
```

Which is, after renaming the type variables, the same as what you started with.

Answer (score 5):

From `f x y z = x y (y z)`, you can reason as follows:

- We don't apply `z` to anything, so it could have some arbitrary type; call it `u1` (for unknown number one).
- `y` is applied to `z`, so its argument type is `u1`, but the return type is another unknown type `u2`. Thus `y :: u1 -> u2`.
- `y z` thus has type `u2`.
- `x` is applied to `y` *and* `y z`, and so must have a type like `(u1 -> u2) -> u2 -> u3`; there's no reason to assume that either argument has the same type, or that either type is the same as the return type.
- The return value of `f` is the same as the return value of `x`, i.e. `u3`.

Putting it altogether, we have

```
f :: ((u1 -> u2) -> u2 -> u3) -> (u1 -> u2) -> u1          ->    u3
     ------------------------    ----------    --                --
         type of x                type of y    type of z        end result of f
```

Because the names of the individual type variables aren't important aside from keeping distinct types separate, we can rename them using

- `u1 ~ b`
- `u2 ~ a`
- `u3 ~ c`

to get the type you looked up

```
f :: ((b  -> a) -> a  -> c) -> (b  -> a) -> b  -> c
```